# Hover and click events not working on <span> inside a <button>

Tags: html, css, button, onclick, hover

Is there anyway my :hover and click events can work on the spans inside of a button?  Currently nothing is happening, presumably because the button functionality is taking priority.

If the button is converted to a div, then everything works.  But - I don't have this option.

Any ideas?

HTML:

```
<button>
<span>item 1 <i onclick="alert('1')">x</i></span>
<span>item 2 <i onclick="alert('2')">x</i></span>
<span>item 3 <i onclick="alert('3')">x</i></span>
</button>
```

CSS

```
i:hover{
    border:1px solid #fff;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/c72qd1o6/

Comment: Can't reproduce. Your own live demo works fine here.

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to use a button here … well, it does, but instead of the italic elements (since those are the things you want the user to interact with) not as the container for everything.

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way because the button tag is container only for text and cannot have any events on child elements.

Comment: I did forgot to tell you that this is not valid for all browsers. Some of them allow for button to nest child elements with events for them, but most of them can't. So taking in mind cross-browser compatibility it is not a good idea to use such child elements inside button.

Comment: Can the definition of the button be modified to act more like a div?  (without changing the element type)

Comment: The way a button is handled is entirely up to the browser. Is there a valid reason you can't use div ?

Comment: "the button tag is container only for text" — Not true, [the spec says](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-button-element) that the content model is "Phrasing content, but there must be no interactive content descendant." not "Text"

Comment: The reason it must be <button> is because I'm using bootstrap select plugin which replaces select elements with buttons for beautification reasons.  I was to modify the button so that i can show comma delimited values as "tags".